# No implementation found for method startV2Ray on channel flutter_v2ray

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to use flutter_v2ray package in my flutter app! But I got an error (see below):

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method startV2Ray on channel flutter_v2ray)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFlutterV2ray.startV2Ray (package:flutter_v2ray/flutter_v2ray_method_channel.dart:42:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterV2ray.startV2Ray (package:flutter_v2ray/flutter_v2ray.dart:71:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I used flutter_v2ray: ^1.0.5! code that I run is the **Example Code** which is in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_v2ray/example)

Why I got this error when I click On **Conncet** button?

I run flutter clean, then flutter pub get, after that flutter run! But it doesn't work.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be running on the iOS platform. I checked the source code and found that the iOS platform has not been implemented yet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eWbd.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).